# testTags() test method not recognized as test in my gradle project, using junit5

Tags: gradle, karate, junit5

I added below test methods to my runner class. When I try to run the testTags() test, I get 'No tests found for given includes: ....' and 'Test events were not received' (in my IDE) errors. I have ensured that the "@test1" tag is a valid tag in my feature file.

The testFullPath() method runs my entire feature, as expected. But when I try to implement other test methods, they are not recognized.

I'm using karate-junit5:0.9.5.RC5

```
package WebServices.Regression;
import com.intuit.karate.junit5.Karate;

public class Regression_Runner {

@Karate.Test
Karate testFullPath() {
    return new Karate().feature("regressionTest.feature").relativeTo(getClass());
}

@Karate.Test
Karate testTags() {
    return new Karate().feature("regressionTest.feature").tags("@test1").relativeTo(getClass());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to have everything `relativeTo(someClass)` just use this form:

```
return Karate.run("classpath:/some/package/regressionTest.feature")
```

Else sorry nothing anyone can do, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Maybe you are better off using the ZIP release: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/ZIP-Release

Comment: I was tinkering with something similar to what you pasted earlier. Problem is I get 'Cannot resolve method 'run' in 'Karate'' .

Comment: @dobogdas whatever it is you are missing something. so unless you submit the whole context, no one can help you